# How to handle article revisions?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, revision-history

I'm creating a knowledge base web app in Ruby on Rails. I'm looking for various ideas on how to handle revisions of the same article.

At this point, I have a table called contents and versions. Versions `belongs_to` the Content table and has a *foreign_key* to `content_ID`. However, from this point on, I'm not sure how I'm going to implement saving to different versions, auto-save, and allow authors to recover from certain version and making a particular version as the current version. Any suggestions, opinions, and links are all appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Version control can be tricky but check out paper_trail: https://github.com/airblade/paper_trail

Comment: Thanks for the response. Do you know if the papertrail gem is able to store multiple versions are just the latest versions?

Comment: multiple versions. It's a version control solution.